# iphone container controller orientation bug

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have an issue with the orientation of my container controller.

When switching between controllers the previous controller tends to stay in whatever orientation it left off in when you switch back.

[image: orientation bug]

First, the steps I use to reproduce:

1. When the container controller is presented I rotate to landscape.
   Everything looks fine in landscape at this point.
2. Switch to child controller #2 via the segmented control.
3. Rotate back to landscape in this view. Everything still looks normal.
4. Switch back to child controller #1.

in ContainerController's viewDidLoad:

```
self.child1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"first"];
self.child2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];

[self addChildViewController:self.child1];
[self addChildViewController:self.child2];

[self.view addSubview:self.child1.view];
```

How I transition the child controllers:

```
- (IBAction)segmentChanged:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *toVc, *fromVc;
    UISegmentedControl *segment = sender;

    if (segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
    {
        toVc = self.child1;
        fromVc = self.child2;  
    }
    else
    {
        toVc = self.child2;
        fromVc = self.child1;
    }

    [toVc willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self transitionFromViewController:fromVc 
                      toViewController:toVc 
                              duration:0.0
                               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone 
                            animations:nil
                            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                [toVc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                            }];
}
```

I had assumed transitionFromViewController would take care of all of that automatically. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution would be to add the following line before transtionFromViewController function is called

```
toVc.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

this should set the frame in the new view correctly

Comment: Wow that was more obvious than I thought it would be. I had figured that would only adjust the frame without redrawing the content.

Answer (score 1):

I like Omar Abdelhafith's answer.  While it will set the frame, it may not rotate the view to the desired orientation.  You will have to test for that.  What can also be done is to check the orientation of the status bar.  Then call the willRotateToOrientation method sending the orientation of the status bar.  I hope this also helps.

Comment: much to my surprise, @Omar Abdelhafith's answer does rotate the view. But this is useful information regardless.